# How to retrieve and group by Week my meteor mongo data?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I would like to retrieve my data and group them by week ?

For example:

```
12/09 - Data1  
12/09 - Data2  
13/09 - Data3    
26/09 - Data4
```

and would like to have them like that:

```
from 12/09 to 19/09     
 1. Data1  
 2. Data2
 3. Data3

from 20/09 to 27/09  
 1. Data4
```

---

### both/collections/hours.js

```
    Hours = new Mongo.Collection("hours");

    Hours.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
      createdBy: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function() {
          return Meteor.userId()
        }
      },
```

//Here's the Day Date I want to retrieve in a Weekly Group

```
date: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Date",
    min: new Date("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    autoform: {
      value: new Date("2014-10-18T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
  }
}));

}
```

---

### client/views/hours.js

```
// List Hours
Template.showHours.helpers({
     hours: function() {
        return ReactiveMethod.call('groupedByWeek');
      }
 });
```

---

### server/server.js

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        groupedByWeek: function() {
            var query = [{
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        $week: "$date"
                    },
                    Data: {
                        $push: "$$ROOT"
                    }
                }
            }]; // This Query will return data grouped by week number. date is the field with date

            return Hours.Data.aggregate(query); // Use your Collection here
        }
    });
```

---

### views/hours/hours.html

```
 {{#each hours}}
    <tr>
                    <td valign="middle">{{formatDateHours date}}</td>
                    <td valign="middle">{{workinghour}}h</td>
                    <td valign="middle">{{class}}</td>
                    <td valign="middle">{{project}}</td>
                    <td valign="middle">{{summary}}</td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="right">
                        <div class="table-icon-buttons">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o edit"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-times delete"></i>
                        </div>
                    </td>
    </tr>
 {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Add `meteorhacks:aggregate` and `simple:reactive-method`
 to your project.

Meteor Allows Aggregation Function only on the server side.

so you will have to write a Meteor Method as Follows

```
Meteor.methods({
    groupedByWeek: function () {

        var query = [
            {$group: {_id: { $week: "$date" }, Data: {$push: "$$ROOT"}}}
        ]; // This Query will return data grouped by week number. date is the field with date

        return Collections.Data.aggregate(query); // Use your Collection here
    }
})
```

Now Inside your Helper call

`return ReactiveMethod.call('groupedByWeek');`

You have to use reactive method otherwise it will return `null` as `Method.call` is async

Hope this Helps !!

Comment: I have this Error


message: Cannot call method 'aggregate' of undefined 

stack:  
TypeError: Cannot call method 'aggregate' of undefined
    at [object Object].Meteor.methods.groupedByWeek (server/server.js:306:21)
    at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2554:1)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1692:12)
    at livedata_server.js:708:19
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
    at livedata_server.js:706:40

Comment: And with the meteorhacks:aggregate package ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that .. yes you have to use the ```meteorhacks:aggregate``` package

Comment: Just return```Hours.aggregate(query)```

Comment: It's working. You're the man.
Can you explain a little bit your code ?
It will be helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you any clue how to do render this reactively ? @gatolgaj

Comment: It should be reactive . Not sure what has gone wrong

Comment: those packages could be a problem ?
reactive-dict
simple:reactive-method
reactive-var
-----
or should i subscribe something ?